# Delphi RAD Server 10.4.2 Two packages sharing common units - Error to load package

Tags: delphi, bpl, rad-server

I had a RAD Server package ProjA.bpl with several endpoints and some of them use a unit called UntAccess.pas.
Now I created another server package ProjB.bpl with different endpoints than ProjA and adjusted emsserver.ini configuration file section [Server.Packages] to call both packages .

The problem appeared when EMS Server starts, it shows the following error message :

{"Thread":32068,"Error":{"Type":"Package","Filename":"C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\Bpl\Win64\ProjDevAPI.bpl","Exception":"EPackageError","Message":"Cannot load package 'ProjB.bpl'  It contains unit 'UntAccess.pas', which is also contained in package 'ProjA.bpl'"}}

How can I share same units among tow or more RAD Server .bpl packages  ?

Environment : Delphi 10.4.2 , Windows 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new package containing that common unit (and probably more in the future). Then add this package as *required* to ProjA and ProjB.

Comment: Thks Uwe.  Let me try it.  I'll back with the results.

Comment: thanks Sir. !   It worked now by following your instructions.  I had to create a Delphi-package  Package_X, putting on it all common units used in both  RAD Server packages (.bpl) ,  then  it generated a .dcp file into C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\Dcp folder,   then I went to each  RAD Server package (.bpl)  removed the common units and added  this newly Package_X .   It's working as expected now !